# How can I use tikz-cd and \mathsurround simultaneously?

Tags: spacing, formatting, tikz-cd

The proper formatting I need to use includes the line `\mathsurround=2pt`, but this ruins the arrow placement in `tikzcd` environments. Can I temporarily turn \mathsurround off, either by recovering the default behavior or else manually placing arrows in my commutative diagrams?

Here is an example of how bad the arrow placement looks with \mathsurround:
[image: Commutative square with arrow shifted to the right of their correct places]

The image above was generated by the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\mathsurround=2pt

\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
      B_{\sigma} (\bar{n}_{\bullet}) \ar[r, "\mathrm{diag}"] \ar[d, "\mathbf{y}_{\mathbf{i}_{\sigma}}" left] &
      B (n_{\bullet}) \ar[d, "\mathbf{y}_{\mathbf{i}}"]
      \\
      A_0^{\mathbf{i}_{\sigma}} (\bar{n}_{\bullet}) \ar[r,  "\iota"] &
      A_0^{\mathbf{i}} (n_{\bullet})
    \end{tikzcd}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `\mathsurround` to zero at each `tikz` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\setlength{\mathsurround}{30pt}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd}{\setlength{\mathsurround}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

Text $0=0$ text
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
B_{\sigma} (\bar{n}_{\bullet}) 
  \arrow[r, "\mathrm{diag}"] 
  \arrow[d, "\mathbf{y}_{\mathbf{i}_{\sigma}}" left] &
B (n_{\bullet}) \arrow[d, "\mathbf{y}_{\mathbf{i}}"]
\\
A_0^{\mathbf{i}_{\sigma}} (\bar{n}_{\bullet}) 
  \arrow[r,  "\iota"] &
A_0^{\mathbf{i}} (n_{\bullet})
\end{tikzcd}
\]
Text $0=0$ text

\end{document}
```

[image]

The value of `\mathsurround` has been set to a humongous value just to make it clear that the setting is resumed after the `tikzcd` environment.

Comment: And just to be sure, this resets the length to 2pt at the end of the tikzcd environment?

Comment: @jackson Yes, I added an example with a very large value just to clearly see that the value is restored.